# what is the homology groups some quotient space of torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

what is the homology group for The quotient space of $S^1 \times S^1$ obtained by identifying points in the circle $S1 \times\{x_0\} $
that differ by $\frac{2 \pi}{m}$ rotation and identifying points in the circle  $\{x_0\} \times S^1 $ that
differ by $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ rotation.

actually it is exercise 2.2.9.d from hatcher and I am really curious  about its homology groups.

it  will be awesome if you can show me an imagination of this space.and I really don't know what tools should I use to calculate homology groups,cellular one,simplicial one,mayer-vietoris...,please help me,it will be great if you give me guidance or hint,thank you very much.

Comment: For a start, draw the torus represented by a *square* in which opposite edge points are identified. We can assume that $x_0$ is just '*the*' corner of this square representation and the two principal circles are just the '*two*' edges. Now make an $m\times n$ grid, at least on the edges.

Comment: the reduced homology of the quotient space is the same as the relative homology $H_\bullet(S^1\times S^1,A)$, where $A$ is the set of the identified points. Now use the long exact sequence for the pair $A\subset S^1\times S^1$.

Comment: thank you very much,I got it.

Comment: @user8268 Wait, how is $A$ a subspace? In particular, it seems like you're saying that our space is $X/A$ for some contractible subspace $A$?

Comment: @user8268 Would you happen to know how to calculate how many points we are identifying? The homology groups depend on the size of $A$.

Comment: @user8268 We are not taking the quotient by a *subspace*. We are taking a quotient via a different kind of equivalence relation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you've got the answer by yourself, I would like to write an answer solving the problem with cellular homology, so that someone who asks the same question can find an answer here. I solved this problem a few month ago in an Algebraic Topology course as an exercise.

**Proof:**

Let $X = S^1\times S^1/ \sim$ be the space with the identifications:

$$(e^{2\pi i/m}z,x_0)\sim (z,x_0)$$

$$(x_0,e^{2\pi i/n}z)\sim (x_0,z)$$

Like @Berci said, you should imagine this space as a grid of $m$  and $n$ lines, i.e. there are $m$ vertical and $n$ horizontal repititions:

[image: Hatcher 2.2.9]

(OK. The picture is not the nicest one, but it's enough to induce an imagination.)

$X$ consists of one 0-cell ($x_0$ is $e_1^0$), two 1-cells ($a$ is $e_1^1$, $b$ is $e_2^1$) and one 2-cell (we all it $e_1^2$).

The attaching map identifies $x\in \partial D_1^2$ with $a^nb^ma^{-n}b^{-m}$.

This implies the cellular chain complex

$$0\to \mathbb{Z}[e_1^2]\overset{\partial_2=0}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}[a] \oplus\mathbb{Z}[b]\overset{\partial_1=0}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}[x_0]\to 0.$$

This implies

$$H_p(X) = 
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}\mbox{ for } p=0,2 \\
\mathbb{Z}^2\mbox{ for } p=1 \\
0\mbox{ for } p>2
\end{cases}.$$

Otherwise you can just see, that the space $X$ is still a Torus (cf. remark above). So it is not surprising, that we've got the [homology group of the Torus](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Homology_of_torus#Homology_groups_in_tabular_form).

Comment: Can you explain why the attaching map is $a^nb^ma^{−n}b^{−m}$ ?

Comment: Consider the attaching map of the torus, which is $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. Because of the identification described above, you now have to attach the 2-cell along $a^nb^ma^{-n}b^{-m}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I think, after identification, it's just the little square, thus should it be just $a^{1/n}b^{1/m}a^{-1/n}b^{-1/m}$?

Comment: Why is $\partial_2 = 0$?

Comment: Shouldn't there be $mn$ $2$-cells?

Comment: I have a problem for this, the hypothesis given in the question actually says that the identification is made after your get the torus and that the identification is only made on the two sphere embeded "in" the torus, so except those two spheres measured zero circling through themselves $n$ and $m$ times respectively all other part(almost all part) of the torus still left untouched. so your figure is misleading.

Comment: Nah, this can be counter-intuitive, but this identification changes structure of the whole torus, not only the neigbourhood of this projection. Think about the projective space for instance - you the common construction also make an identification "only at the boundary of a disk", but it changes the space drastically not only on the null set