# Confusion about cellular homology.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have been trying to do some computations with cellular homology and I've run into a weird issue that I was hoping someone could help me with. A good example for this issue is computing the homology of $X = S^1 \times S^1/\sim$ where $\sim$ identifies $\{x_0\} \times S^1$ with $2\pi/n$ rotations and $S^1 \times \{x_0\}$ with $2\pi/m$ rotations.

There is a solution to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811169/what-is-the-homology-groups-some-quotient-space-of-torus), which visualizes $X$ as a CW-complex, by writing it as a quotient of the square by subdividing it into $nm$ rectangles and identifying all of the horizontal (resp. vertical) lines together and points.

In the solution, they just use one $2$-cell, with boundary $a^m b^n a^{-m} b^{-n}$, where $a$ and $b$ represent the two loops obtained from the identifications above. As such, the $2$-skeleton is one $2$-cell, the $1$-skeleton is just the loops $a$ and $b$, and the zero skeleton is a point. Moreover, we can see that the boundary map here is the zero map, since identifying $a$ or $b$ to a point makes the boundary of our 2-cell the 0-loop, so the homology is the homology of the chain complex $$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
where the maps are all zero.

Now here's my confusion. Couldn't we also take $nm$ 2-cells, corresponding the all the $nm$ rectangles in the square, each with boundary $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$? In this case, we would have the complex

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}^{nm} \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

again, where the maps are zero. This would clearly give different homology, so something certainly went wrong. I'm not sure what, though.

What goes wrong here? Am I misunderstanding how cellular homology works?

Thanks!

Comment: You're introducing a lot more identifications than were present in the original quotient space, are you not?

Comment: @TedShifrin To me it seems like the linked solution doesn't make enough identifications. Since when we subdivide the square in all the rectangles, we should be identifying all the points of intersection, right? Since these points are all $2\pi/m$ or $2\pi/n$ rotations of each other.

Comment: No, you're making the identification not just on $\{x_0\}\times S^1$, but on $m$ copies of it, etc.

Comment: Oh I think I see. So we're just making these identifications on one circle in either coordinate, not all of them. This makes sense now. Thanks so much!